# Decoding 433Mhz AC123-01 signal, transmitter not receiving controller info

Tags: arduino, signals, decoding, binary-data, waveform

I'm trying to copy a 433Mhz wave from the Air conditioner controller with a 433 receiver, I was able to get the wave with some code, but this wave didn't help me at all, I have a AC123-01 controller. I am using a receiver and transmitter RF modules for Arduino. I tried the RC-Switch library for gathering the binary code from the controller but didn't have any success.

This is the controller I want to copy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_PyVQf_4i8
The code I manage to get the wave form:

```
#define DATA 2

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(DATA, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println(digitalRead(DATA));
}
```

This is the controller and my Arduino with the transmitter:
[image: My Setup]

With this code from Rc-Switch library, I can't catch any type of signal from my controller. There is no response at all:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
}

void loop() {
if (mySwitch.available()) {
output(mySwitch.getReceivedValue(), mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength(), 
mySwitch.getReceivedDelay(), 
mySwitch.getReceivedRawdata(),mySwitch.getReceivedProtocol());
mySwitch.resetAvailable();
}
}
```

I manage to use a website to get the waves, the first two lines are from the down button, and the other two lines are from UP button.
[image: Waves]
Raw Data got from the Controller:

```
Start here first frame =>888,5208,648,556,252,152,648,548,248,156,648,
156,644,160,648,548,240,
564,248,156,648,160,644,552,244,556,248,156,656,540,268,144,648,548,256,148,
660,148,656,144,648,552,252,148,660,536,260,152,640,556,252,156,644,160,644,
552,240,172,632,564,244,548,256,548,244,168,640,160,648,156,652,152,644,160,
648,144,652,152,656,148,644,552,256,148,652,152,652,152,636,172,636,156,
648,156,644,160,628,176,632,164,640,568,240,160,632,172,628,164,644,160,648
,548,260,540,256,552,256,148,656,540,264,540,256,548,256,548,252,148,656
,152,636,556<=end frame
start next 
frame=>884,5220,640,560,252,148,656,540,260,152,660,136,664,140,664,
532,264,540,264,140,660,144,664,532,256,548,256,148,652,552,248,156,636,
560,248,156,648,160,644,160,644,548,248,156,648,556,252,152,656,536,264,
140,664,140,664,532,276,136,656,540,264,540,268,528,268,144,652,156,640,
152,652,152,648,160,636,168,632,160,644,160,644,552,244,172,632,160,644,
160,648,156,640,164,640,152,656,148,656,148,652,152,644,552,252,148,656,
152,640,164,640,152,648,548,252,552,244,564,240,164,640,552,256,548,244,
564,240,564,240,160,648,156,636,556<=end frame
start next frame=>892,5212,648,548,252,152,656,540,260,
156,636,164,640,156,648,548,256,548,248,168,636,160,648,544,260,544,252,
160,652,544,264,136,660,536,260,156,648,148,660,144,660,536,252,160,644,
548,252,156,648,544,252,164,636,160,648,560,236,164,632,564,244,560,
244,560,244,156,644,164,640,152,660,144,656,148,644,160,648,144,656,
152,648,544,264,152,644,148,648,160,644,160,640,164,632,160,640,164,
640,164,644,160,632,564,236,168,640,160,644,160,636,168,640,556,248,
544,264,544,248,164,640,552,252,544,260,544,252,552,248,156,648,156
,640,552,3300,84,484,672,160<=end frame
```

Normalizing the data from the 3 frames in Excel:
[image: wave]

Comment: Im stuck in the same problem... With this library im not able to read the data from my remote controler.. I press all buttons and the serial reader dont show notting.

Answer (score 4):

**How to decode**
To get the codes in binary format to use you [download the library RC_switch 2.6.3](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch/archive/master.zip) and install it to your library dir via `Sketch -> Library manager -> Add zip library` . 
Then load the `File > Examples > RC_Switch > ReceiveDemo_Advanced` and compole to the board.
After uploading the sketch, connect an 433MHz RF receiver to `Digital Pin 2` of your Arduino UNO board. Open the Arduino IDE serial monitor and start pressing the buttons of your remote.
After pressing each button one time, you can see the binary code for each button (it’s highlighted in red):
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]
Save your binary codes for each button press (you can also use the Decimal or Tri-State codes):

```
Button 3 ON = (24Bit) Binary: 000101010101000101010101
Button 3 OFF = (24Bit) Binary: 000101010101000101010100
Button 4 ON = (24Bit) Binary: 000101010101010001010101
Button 4 OFF = (24Bit) Binary: 000101010101010001010100
```

Save your Pulse Length: 416 Microseconds and Protocol: 1.

**How to send**
You'll need to customize the next sketch with your binary codes, pulse length and protocol:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Transmitter is connected to Arduino Pin #10  
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(10);

  // Optional set pulse length.
  mySwitch.setPulseLength(REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PULSE_LENGTH);
  // Optional set protocol (default is 1, will work for most appliancies)
  mySwitch.setProtocol(REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PROTOCOL);

  // Optional set number of transmission repetitions.
  // mySwitch.setRepeatTransmit(15);
}
void loop() {
  // Binary code - button 3 ON
  mySwitch.send("000101010101000101010101");  // YOUR_CODE_HERE
  delay(1000); 
 // Binary code - button 3 OFF 
  mySwitch.send("000101010101000101010100");   // YOUR_CODE_HERE
  delay(1000);
  // Binary code - button 4 ON
  mySwitch.send("000101010101010001010101");    // YOUR_CODE_HERE
  delay(1000);  
 // Binary code - button 4 OFF
  mySwitch.send("000101010101010001010100");    // YOUR_CODE_HERE
  delay(1000);
}
```

So no cutting wave signals or similar, just systematic pressing buttons recording and replaying.
**EDIT**
For your special need decoding AC123 protocol there is a solution.
Decoding is done by adapting the given transmitter program below and the [fork of the RC-switch library](https://github.com/perivar/rc-switch/). As AC123 uses 2-sync-bits and 64 data bytes. The protocol settings (add only to the pevar library) are:

```
 {15, 132, 50, {99, 13}, {5, 13}, {11, 6}, {11, 101}, false }
```

How to add a [new remote read this wiki](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch/wiki/Add_New_Remote_Part_1) but use the forked libraray. As a help if you use the simple_scanner (in examples) you get something like where you search for the first 844 (thirvalue - in this example 840 yours might be 860 or similar) from the next number till the last number before the next 844 (what your first was) is the code as an int array:

```
212,572,
from =>844,5144,596,576,212,180,612,564,212,192,600,180,608,
180,608,564,216,576,216,180,608,180,612,564,212,576,212,576,
216,564,224,180,600,188,604,180,608,576,212,564,216,576,212,
180,612,572,216,180,596,192,604,180,608,572,216,180,600,576,
212,180,612,572,216,180,608,564,216,180,612,180,608,180,608,
180,600,180,608,180,612,180,608,564,216,184,608,180,608,184,
608,180,596,192,600,180,608,180,608,180,604,188,600,576,212,
184,608,180,596,192,600,180,608,564,224,564,220,188,600,576,
212,180,608,180,600,576,216,176,612,180,608,564,212,
576<= till here
,844,5140,600,572,216,176,612,568,220,180,600,
180,612,180,608,564,224,564,220,180,608,180,608,564,228,560,
216,572,216,572   .... goes on for x lines
```

The array can be sent with [this fork of the library of RC-switch](https://github.com/Martin-Laclaustra/rc-switch/tree/transmittimingsarray) by adding ,0 at the end of the array

For sending a self generated signal you have to use [this fork of the library](https://github.com/perivar/rc-switch/) after you have analysed the data load according to the wiki
The protocol of an AC123 is built like this (you still have to use RC_Scanner to get the data for your hardware!):

```
Remote ID Byte 1 (possibly Manufacturer ID)    10100011
Remote ID Byte 2                               01101110 
Remote ID Byte 3                               00010100
Remote ID Byte 4                               00110101      
Channel Byte 1                                 00000001
Channel Byte 2                                 00000000    
Control Code                                   00001011  
Checksum                                      11000011
 The command byte works as follows for my system:
 UP         STOP            DOWN
00001011    00100011    01000011
```

The checksum is calculated as the addition of Remote ID Byte 2 + Remote ID Byte 3 + Remote ID Byte 4 + Channel Byte 1 + Channel Byte 2 + Control Code. This may add up to more than 1 byte in which case the MSB are ignored. 
Note: This excludes the Remote ID Byte 1 which may point to that being a Manufacturer ID.
Here is a quicktest sketch to use and experiment with:

```
// Transmitter for AC123 - Manufacturer ID 1
#include <RCSwitch.h> // Use this lib variant: https://github.com/perivar/rc-switch/

const unsigned long Remote = 0xA362281F;

const uint8_t CHANNEL_PADDING = B0000;
const uint8_t UP = B00001011;
const uint8_t STOP = B00100011;
const uint8_t DOWN = B01000011;

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Transmitter is connected to Pin 5 change to your setuo
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(5);
  // AC123 Protocol define as 15
  mySwitch.setProtocol(15);
  mySwitch.setPulseLength(50);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Send Command");
  sendCommand(Remote, B00001111, DOWN);
  delay(2000);
  sendCommand(Remote, B00001111, STOP);
  delay(2000);
  sendCommand(Remote, B00001111, UP);
  delay(2000);
}

void comUp(unsigned long Remote, uint8_t channels) {
  sendCommand(Remote, channels, UP);
}

void comDown(unsigned long Remote, uint8_t channels) {
  sendCommand(Remote, channels, DOWN);
}

void comStop(unsigned long Remote, uint8_t channels) {
  sendCommand(Remote, channels, STOP);
}
// This is the part you'll have to adept to your hardware
void sendCommand(unsigned long Remote, uint8_t channels, uint8_t commandR) {
  uint8_t RemoteByte1 __attribute__((unused)) = Remote >> 24; // possibly Manufacturer ID not used at the moment
  uint8_t RemoteByte2 = Remote >> 16;
  uint8_t RemoteByte3 = Remote >> 8;
  uint8_t RemoteByte4 = Remote;
  uint8_t Checksum = RemoteByte2 + RemoteByte3 + RemoteByte4 + channels + CHANNEL_PADDING + commandR;
  char SendCodeChar[64];
  uint8_t bitPos = 31;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
    if bitRead(Remote, bitPos) SendCodeChar[i] = '1';
    else SendCodeChar[i] = '0';
    bitPos--;
  }
  bitPos = 7;
  for (uint8_t i = 32; i <= 39 ; i++) {
    if bitRead(channels, bitPos) SendCodeChar[i] = '1';
    else SendCodeChar[i] = '0';
    bitPos--;
  }
  bitPos = 7;
  for (uint8_t i = 40; i <= 47 ; i++) {
    if bitRead(CHANNEL_PADDING, bitPos) SendCodeChar[i] = '1';
    else SendCodeChar[i] = '0';
    bitPos--;
  }
  bitPos = 7;
  for (uint8_t i = 48; i <= 55 ; i++) {
    if bitRead(commandR, bitPos) SendCodeChar[i] = '1';
    else SendCodeChar[i] = '0';
    bitPos--;
  }
  bitPos = 7;
  for (uint8_t i = 56; i <= 63 ; i++) {
    if bitRead(Checksum, bitPos) SendCodeChar[i] = '1';
    else SendCodeChar[i] = '0';
    bitPos--;
  }
  mySwitch.send(SendCodeChar);
}
```

**EDIT 2**
As the OP changed his question and added captured data (its working OMG) here the answer I gave in a discussion as help for others how to decode.
I analysed in a spreadsheet and you should search for combinations of 8xx (pulse) and 5XXX (encoding AC123-0x) in your case a frame is including the commas always 1750 chars long

```
Start here first frame =>888,5208,648,556,252,152,648,548,248,156,648,
156,644,160,648,548,240,
564,248,156,648,160,644,552,244,556,248,156,656,540,268,144,648,548,256,148,
660,148,656,144,648,552,252,148,660,536,260,152,640,556,252,156,644,160,644,
552,240,172,632,564,244,548,256,548,244,168,640,160,648,156,652,152,644,160,
648,144,652,152,656,148,644,552,256,148,652,152,652,152,636,172,636,156,
648,156,644,160,628,176,632,164,640,568,240,160,632,172,628,164,644,160,648
,548,260,540,256,552,256,148,656,540,264,540,256,548,256,548,252,148,656
,152,636,556<=end frame
start next frame=>884,5220,640,560,252,148,656,540,260,152,660,136,664,140,664,
532,264,540,264,140,660,144,664,532,256,548,256,148,652,552,248,156,636,
560,248,156,648,160,644,160,644,548,248,156,648,556,252,152,656,536,264,
140,664,140,664,532,276,136,656,540,264,540,268,528,268,144,652,156,640,
152,652,152,648,160,636,168,632,160,644,160,644,552,244,172,632,160,644,
160,648,156,640,164,640,152,656,148,656,148,652,152,644,552,252,148,656,
152,640,164,640,152,648,548,252,552,244,564,240,164,640,552,256,548,244,
564,240,564,240,160,648,156,636,556<=end frame
start next frame=>892,5212,648,548,252,152,656,540,260,
156,636,164,640,156,648,548,256,548,248,168,636,160,648,544,260,544,252,
160,652,544,264,136,660,536,260,156,648,148,660,144,660,536,252,160,644,
548,252,156,648,544,252,164,636,160,648,560,236,164,632,564,244,560,
244,560,244,156,644,164,640,152,660,144,656,148,644,160,648,144,656,
152,648,544,264,152,644,148,648,160,644,160,640,164,632,160,640,164,
640,164,644,160,632,564,236,168,640,160,644,160,636,168,640,556,248,
544,264,544,248,164,640,552,252,544,260,544,252,552,248,156,648,156
,640,552,3300,84,484,672,160<=end frame
```

So actaully you have three commands in your posted code. Do not forget to add ,0 at the end before transmitting as an array

Comment: As I said in my question, I didn't have any success with this library!

Comment: I doesn't receive the signal from the controller

Comment: So, This 2 codes that you edited are for sending the data with the (Transmitter right)? But I can't this receive the code when I press the button on My AC123.

Comment: When you meant that I need the Remote ID, that means I don't need the Rc-Switch sketch ReceiveDemo_Advanced to obtain my binary stuff?

Comment: Now I am completly lost - do you want the Arduino to send to your application or do you want to "indluence/steer" your Arduino with your remote? There are two parts in my edit read them carefully.The first is NO code its the protocol definition for AC123, the second is a test program to make your Arduino to a remote (for home automation etc.) with all givenbits you can start to explore your AC123 appliance.  Test it and give feedback

Comment: So, I edit to try to explain better. What I am trying to do is, I have a controller (AC123-01), I'm trying to get its frequency so I can use it in my 433 transmitters. But the Rc-Switch library (ReceiveDemo_Advanced) doesn't get any response from the controller at all. After I find a way of getting the signal from the controller, I want to manage to send it.

Comment: See my little dissertation I added, if you can not receive there is a config/HW error somewhere try also simple scanner and use the forks each fulfills a specific task. Do not mix themup!

Comment: I could afford to get the wave from the sketch that you passed me, but still no success with the Rc-Switch libraries, even adding those protocols.

Comment: When you meant "Is the code as an int array" my should be from the start of the big one, 5236.... until 5232? from the wave that's under all of the other.

Comment: Nonot from the big one but from the pulse one look at my example it the third on before the "big one" and till the next pulse ID excluding it . Please read my instructions carefully its all there

Comment: So you mean I should get always after the 572 signal? Like in my first wave from the top, it would be 620,572 from->872,5220,632...until I find another number before 872?

Comment: I updated my question with the code, If you could have a look plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212687/discussion-between-codebreaker007-and-nilton-schumacher-f).